# Converting tabs to spaces in sublime by default

Tags: sublimetext2

I use tabs to indent, but I set it so that it uses spaces to tab. I use the text editor Sublime. I manually set it in the lower right hand corner where it says "Tab Size:". For each file I have to manually set this. I have not yet found a solution to make what I want the default. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open your user settings via "Preferences >> Settings - User" and add these two settings. Change the tab size to the size you prefer:

```js
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
```

In general you can just open the default settings and search for the setting you would like to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know if there is a way to turn on the ruler (found in View>Ruler>) by default?

Comment: Just use the `rulers` setting, e.g. `"rulers": [70, 80]` for a ruler behind column 70 and one behind colum 80.